# Norms inducing non discrete Hausdorff topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

We know that any norm defined on a vector space V induces a non discrete Hausdorff Topology on V. Is the converse true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a finite dimensional space, any two norms are equivalent, in particular, the topologies generated are the same. So any non-standard non-discrete Hausdorff topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ would serve as a counterexample to the converse.

In particular, one can take the [lower limit topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

What is the converse ? Is it: "A non-discrete Hausdorff topology on $V$ is induced by a norm." ?

This is wrong: for instance, the topology of uniforme convergence on compacts (or compact-open topology) for real functions defined on the reals is not induced by a norm.

Comment: Any simplier topology plz. I don't know so much about compact-open topology.

Comment: This is the topology for which $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ iff for all compact sets $K$, $f_n$ tends to $f$ uniformly on $K$. I think this is one of the simplest example of a topology not induced by a norm.